# Trouble using Mixins with my Backbone Views

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, mixins

I would like to use mixins with my BackBone Views.

Here is my mixin:

```
var mixin = {
  events: {
    "click" : "doStuff"
  },
  doStuff: function() { alert("bah!"); }
}
```

Here is how I mix it into two separate views:

```
var view1 = Backbone.View.Extend({ ... });
_.extend(view1.prototype, mixin);

var view2 = Backbone.View.Extend({ ... });
_.extend(view2.prototype, mixin);
```

The trouble I am running into is that the click event only seems to work in `view1`.  If I initialize `view`2 first, then the click event only works in `view2`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Comment: It should work fine, double check your code (http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/C9wew/4404/)

Comment: As an aside, including `events` in a mixin won't work very well since `_.extend` won't recursively extend.

Comment: @dsfq - you are correct, it was a problem with a collision.  I have switched to using the Cocktail library that handles collisions automatically, and it works as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the extend method on backbone to due the sort of inheritance and merging you expect. You just need to dig through the documentation a little bit and the objects to find what you want.

This way you have a BaseObject then extend off of that your two objects.